# ImageView not showing image Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

[All my code (links to imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT53X.png)

Why does the image not show up in the emulator?

All code in case you don't want to click the link above:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'white'
});

var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: '/images/name.png',
    width:200
});

win.add(image);

win.open();
```

In the link above you can see there are no spelling mistakes or anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify a height for the `ImageView`.

```
var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: '/images/name.png',
    width:200,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE
});
```

Either make it `Ti.UI.SIZE` if you want to make it dynamic (if you don't know the height yet) or give it a fixed height.

Comment: Thanks so much, in all the tutorials I watched people said "you only need to specify height OR width because it will automatically scale". I guess since they made the tutorial there has been updates that changed that or something.